# Spring boot postgreSql with multiple parameters

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-repositories

I have some Spring Boot problems. I use PostgreSql and would like to find Person by giving 3 hobby-parameters. 
I have a working example with 1 parameter....

```
public interface SubjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Subject, Long> {
    Collection<Person> findByPersonsHobbyId(String hobbyId1);
}
```

... but I wonder if there is some simular sollution to this?

```
public interface SubjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Subject, Long> {
    Collection<Person> findByPersonsHobbyId(Set<String> hobbyIds);
}
```

or like this one...

```
public interface SubjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Subject, Long> {
    Collection<Person> findByPersonsHobbyId(String hobbyId1, String hobbyId2, 
        String hobbyId3);
}
```

UPDATE

Hobbyentity.

```
package com.proj.db_proj;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;

import net.minidev.json.annotate.JsonIgnore;


@Entity
@Table(name="Hobby")
public class Hobby implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1442665206056041894L;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        },
        mappedBy = "hobby")
    private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    protected Hobby() {
    }

    public Hobby(String title) {
        this.title = title;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hobby [persons=" + persons + ", id=" + id + ", title=" + 
        title + "]";
    }

    public Set<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(Set<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

}
```

And the owning person entity

```
package com.proj.db_proj;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;

import net.minidev.json.annotate.JsonIgnore;
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable {


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "person_hobby",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "hobby_id") })
    private Set<Hobby> hobby = new HashSet<>();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4582624077512606651L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;


    protected Person() {
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Person[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']", 
id, firstName, lastName);
    }

    public Set<Hobby> getHobby() {
        return hobby;
    }

    public void setHobby(Set<Hobby> hobby) {
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }


}
```

Would apprichiate help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `In` when using collections as input

```
public interface SubjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Subject, Long> {
    Collection<Person> findByPersonsHobbyIdIn(Set<String> hobbyIds);
}
```

Refer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords) for more such keywords.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it tonight

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. I have tried it with another table mapped to this with ManyToMany and that worked fine, can the ManyToMany make it problem.

Comment: Can you post the method which did not work for you and the related entities to see why it did not work?

Comment: H. I do that tonight after work Believed I was making wrong calls and didn't think that would be neccesary.

Answer (score 0):

For the second variant, you may use follow construction

```
public interface SubjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Subject, Long> {

    @Query("select p from Person p where p.hobbyId in ( :hobbyId1, :hobbyId2, :hobbyId3 ")
    List<Person> findByPersonsHobbyId(@Param("hobbyId1") String hobbyId1, @Param("hobbyId2") String hobbyId2, @Param("hobbyId3") String hobbyId3);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Gonna test it tomorrow

Comment: Tried this in any way I could and always got this 2018-02-17 12:09:45.764 ERROR 7836 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 1:87: expecting CLOSE, found 'null'
2018-02-17 12:09:45.764 ERROR 7836 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 1:87: expecting CLOSE, found 'null'

antlr.MismatchedTokenException: expecting CLOSE, found 'null'
 at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211) ~[antlr-2.7.7.jar:na]

Comment: After some more testing I guess the problem is with Person entity. Selecting Hobbys wthout Personparameters work